# Opening a file and clicking to a button from Touch Bar in electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I implemented a touch bar button to my program which loads a file. My question is: How can I click to a specific button on the website after that page has loaded when I press the touch bar button? Here is my `main.js` file:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, TouchBar } = require('electron')
const { TouchBarButton } = TouchBar
const path = require('path')

let window

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1366,
        height: 758,
        minWidth: 1300,
        minHeight: 700,
        icon: __dirname + 'logoSquare.icns',
        webPreferences: {
            //preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })
    win.loadFile('login.html')
    win.maximize()
    return win
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    window = createWindow()

    const button = new TouchBarButton({
      label: ` Add Flight`,
      accessibilityLabel: 'Add Flight',
      backgroundColor: '#a20021',
      click: () => {
        window.loadFile('./flights.html')
      },
    });
    const touchBar = new TouchBar({
      items: [
        button,
      ],
    })

    window.setTouchBar(touchBar);

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow()
        }
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})
```

I have just started learning electron.js and couldn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate way to solve this issue. I sent a query and got that information with JavaScript. This is the main.js file that is responsible for sending the query:

```
const button = new TouchBarButton({
    label: ` Add Flight`,
    accessibilityLabel: 'Add Flight',
    backgroundColor: '#3a2e39',
    click: () => {
        //window.loadFile('./flights.html?addflight=1')
        window.loadURL('file://'+__dirname+'/flights.html?addflight=1')
    },
})
```

And this is the code that is responsible for receiving data in the `flights.html` file with JavaScript:

```
function addFlightRedir() {
    if (location.search == '?addflight=1') {
        addNewFlight(); // This is the code that I wanted to execute
    }
}

addFlightRedir();
```

And since it is reusable with standard JS, now I can implement it to the other areas of my program as well (independent from the Touch Bar buttons).